# Using Array returning function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to define an array of object from a function but I always get the Compile error `Can't assign to array`.

Here is my code:

```
Dim param1 As String
Dim param2 As String
Dim my_legs(1 To 4) As MyObject_Obj

Set my_legs = legBuilder(param1,param2)


private Function legbuilder (ByVal param1 As String,ByVal param2 As String)As MyObject_Obj

Dim my_legs(1 To 4) As MyObject_Obj

---Filling my Array---

legBuilder = my_legs

End Function
```

It seems that my function is, by design not returning the expected type (an Array of `MyObject_Obj`)

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Is MyObject_Obj a custom type you created? Where is its declaration?

Comment: It is an object coming from my References. I actually simplified quite much on purpose here. My point is to know if I can use function(with parameters) to return an array of custom object.

Comment: Show the type declaration or there's no way to answer your question. "coming from references" is not the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Function ReturnArray(param1,param2) as variant
Dim A(4) as variant
A(0) = "One"
A(1) = "Two"
A(2)= "Three"
A(3) = "Four"
ReturnArray = A()
End Function

Sub test()
 MsgBox ReturnArray("A", "B")(2)

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the rest, you can't do

```
Set my_legs = legbuilder(param1, param2)
```

Set is for objects. Your "custom" `legbuilder` is essentially returning an array ,so drop the `Set`.

Comment: A line like?  As per @ThomasG's comment - where is the code governing the custom type you have created (MyObject_Obj). You are treating it as an array so you can't use the Set keyword. You declare things in the same way Dim x As ***type***

Answer (score 0):

```
private Function legbuilder (...) As MyObject_Obj()
```